# Applying a nonlinear regression model to assess the difference between variables

Tags: regression, correlation, nonlinear-regression, convergence

I have two variables which represent attitudes towards slightly different sorts of people, though measured with the same scale.

I also have a superordinate variable which is a certain psychological trait and which I'd like to correlate with the other two variables.

The aim of my study is to verify empirically a certain implication of the theoretical framework behind the superordinate variable which led me to assume that higher scores on that scale would be associated with the attitudes becoming less different to each other or even identical, as measured for each individual subject; one of the objects would be evaluated more positively on the whole (the line of regression would look noticeably less steep than the other) but as the value of the superordinate trait increases they would sort of "converge".

Admittedly, I'm not well versed in statistics and the only way to test that assumption which I could conceive was to calculate the difference between the scores on the attitude scale and then correlate them with the scores on the superordinate scale, hypothesising that if my prediction was true, there would be a negative correlation.

Now, I've got two problems.

1. As a matter of fact, due to some theoretical implications that I believe it's unnecessary to disclose here, a genuine linear relationship between the difference in observed values of the dependent scales and the main scale might not exist; instead, there's a possibility that until a certain undetermined point, lower scores on the main scale would also be associated with smaller differences between attitudes, resulting in a nonlinear regression model. Now, how do I deal with this, considering that I'm planning to test the mediating effects of several other variables to whose relationship with the main scale a simpler linear model might be better applicable?
2. As I've mentioned, I don't know all that much about statistics and it's possible that I've taken the wrong path in assuming that I should apply basic regression models to achieve what I have in mind. As I suspect, linear regression might not best reflect the distributions of the observed values on the attitude scales; after all, they're supposed to "level out" at some point, figuratively speaking. What are the alternatives, then? - i. e., what are the other methods which can be employed to assess the relationship between those attitudes and the superordinate scale? I have already considered cluster analysis, though it might be difficult to obtain a set of discernible subgroups to make it useful.

This is what I imagine the chart might look like if I employed linear regression like Pearson's coefficient (sorry for the visual aspect). The Y axis represents the superordinate variable, the X axis the attitude scale and the coloured dots stand for observations attained for the two different people, along with corresponding lines of regression.

[image]

The thing is, I'm not sure if the pictured regression would be particularly useful in determining the validity of my hypothesis, because I'm not just testing whether there is a statistically significant positive correlation between those attitudes and the main variable; rather, I would like to learn if their lines of regression would start to converge at a certain point. I'm wondering if it's more accurate to consider a nonlinear regression, like the one pictured below:

[image]

But then again, I don't have any clue about particular statistical methods of verifying whether such a relationship exists, and this is, besides other things, what I would like to learn from this inquiry.

Comment: Welcome to CV, curious.  Please explain what you mean by "converge" and what it means to "have" dependent variables.  For instance, are you given data or a mathematical formula?  If it's the former, can you obtain more data or not?  Are you looking at a causal relationship ("as ... increases") or just an association?  Even then, we can't tell you the best way to proceed without details about these variables.  Please feel free to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.  One more followup question: could you describe what you mean by "less differentiated"?  How is that measured or quantified?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This is the exact issue I'm facing, actually, as I can't think of any other way of conceptualizing that difference other than what I've already described; really, I'm just looking for suggestions, as I'm afraid that my own solution would end up muddled up and I would have to resort to a more complex model of regression. I might upload a chart to help visualize what I have in mind if necessary.

Comment: I think what you want is to fit a curve between a) The superordinate variable and b) The difference between the two attitudes.  William Cleveland did some work no this, in a very difference context, and found that it's much easier to look at the difference directly that it is to sort of impute the difference in our heads (he was working with imports and exports to Britain, and it was much easier to look at deficit surplus).