# Applying a non-linear model to assess the difference between variables

Tags: regression, correlation, nonlinear-regression

I have already asked a similar question on this site ([Correlating two variables / convergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633137/correlating-two-variables-convergence)); however, I feel like the way I wrote the previous one made it a bit too ambiguous, and on top of that, there are several aspects of the issue I'm facing that I left out from there. Feel free to remove that post.

I have two variables which represent attitudes towards slightly different sorts of people, though measured with the same scale.

I also have a superordinate variable which is a certain psychological trait and which I'd like to correlate with the other two variables.

The aim of my study is to verify empirically a certain implication of the theoretical framework behind the superordinate variable which led me to assume that higher scores on that scale would be associated with the attitudes becoming less different to each other or even identical, as measured for each individual subject; one of the objects would be evaluated more positively on the whole (the line of regression would look noticeably less steep than the other) but as the value of the superordinate trait increases they would sort of "converge".

Admittedly, I'm not well versed in statistics and the only way to test that assumption which I could conceive was to calculate the difference between the scores on the attitude scale and then correlate them with the scores on the superordinate scale, hypothesising that if my prediction was true, there would be a negative correlation.

Now, I've got two problems.

1. As a matter of fact, due to some theoretical implications that I believe it's unnecessary to disclose here, a genuine linear relationship between the difference in observed values of the dependent scales and the main scale might *not exist*; instead, there's a possibility that until a certain undetermined point, lower scores on the main scale would also be associated with smaller differences between attitudes, resulting in a nonlinear regression model. Now, how do I deal with this, considering that I'm planning to test the mediating effects of several other variables to whose relationship with the main scale a simpler linear model might be better applicable?
2. As I've mentioned, I don't know all that much about statistics and it's possible that I've taken the wrong path in assuming that I should apply basic regression models to achieve what I have in mind. As I suspect, linear regression might not best reflect the distributions of the observed values on the attitude scales; after all, they're supposed to "level out" at some point, figuratively speaking. What are the alternatives, then? - i. e., what are the other methods which can be employed to assess the relationship between those attitudes and the superordinate scale? I have already considered cluster analysis, though it might be difficult to obtain a set of discernible subgroups to make it useful.

Comment: Please don't ask us to clean up after you: just edit your original post.

Comment: Done. I'm sorry.